# Answered my own question with 13 votes. Eligible for enlightened badge?

Tags: support, answers, badges, enlightened-badge

I have answered my own [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22470628/1740715)  with answer score of 13. I am the only one who answered that question and accepted the answer. But I didn't get `enlightened` badge. Is it because the question is asked by me?  Am I eligible for `enlightened` badge?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

Self answers are not eligible for the enlightened badge.

Comment: That's a shame - especially if/when they get highly upvoted. Seems they should be eligible, though maybe on a higher threshold (eg 20 votes instead of 10).

Comment: @warren - suggest it as a [meta-tag:feature-request] - though I don't think it'll go do that well.

Comment: done: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/235311/131197