# Allow enlightened badge on self-answered questions

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, badges

ChrisF [answered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/235300/131197) a previous [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/235298/131197) about being awarded the Enlightened badge - specifically that you cannot get it for a self-answered question.

I suggest that you *should* be able to get it on a self-answered question, but the threshold for awarding should be higher (eg 25 votes instead of 10).

Comment: You still have the problem that self-acceptances add no information to the answer. There's no reason to give someone an extra badge on an answer *just* for clicking a checkmark next to the answer.

Comment: @murgatroid99 - then why have the badge at all?

Comment: @murgatroid99 Wouldn't that be flagged for mod attention?

Comment: @warren Because it *does* make sense to get the badge for *someone else* clicking the check mark on your answer. That indicates that you helped them.

Comment: @monksy Why would accepting your own answer be flagged? That's an established function of the site.

Comment: @murgatroid99 hence the requirement it be at a higher vote count - also: there is nothing that says you're guaranteed to accept your own answer - I've accepted others over mine many times.

Comment: @murgatroid99 I made the comment within the edge case you presented [where no new information was presented and it was for self karma building purposes]

Comment: @monksy I don't think you understand what I'm saying. The *act* of accepting your own answer adds no information. You're saying "my own answer helped me." Well of course it did; otherwise you wouldn't have posted it. It's *supposed* to mean that the answer helped you the most, but it doesn't have to. Anyone can click that button on their own self answer any time they want. There's no sense in rewarding that behavior because getting **yourself** to accept an answer is not an accomplishment.

Comment: From my point of view: The act of accepting your answer meant that the answer posted was correct and solved the question asked. It did add information to the context and to the technical discussion.

Comment: So if someone posted a self answer but they *also* got another answer that is *better* you want to incentivise the OP to accept their own answer over the better one because they can get a shiny badge? *Not* a good idea!

Comment: @MartijnPieters - if the other answer is *better*, of course they'll pick it. Hence the requirement for a self-assigned `Enlightened` badge to have a higher vote threshold.

Comment: @warren: right, so they are close to the threshold, and *then* a new answer is posted. That answer is miles better, but hasn't yet gotten many upvotes. There is now no incentive to accept that better answer, because, you know, just a few more upvotes would get you that badge..

Comment: @MartijnPieters - if you're at 24 votes (needing just one more for your self-answered and -accepted answer to get `Enlightened`), and someone comes along with a "miles better" answer - it's ***ALREADY*** too late for the other answer to even be **considered** for `Enlightened` - they weren't first.

Comment: But your proposal would provide an incentive for a user to accept their own answer which was first instead of another user's answer which was better/more helpful. Accepting an answer isn't *just* about the Enlightened badge; there's reputation involved and it is an indication that the answer was most helpful. Your proposal would incentivize people to violate that assumption.

Comment: @murgatroid99 - this only matters if theirs is *first*: a pretty uncommon occurrence

Comment: It is **trivially** easy to be the first to answer your own question; in fact, it is [explicitly encouraged.](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) The "Ask Question" interface has a button to post an answer with the question.

Comment: @murgatroid99 - yes, it's "trivially easy" to answer your own questions (even first). But for that to be upvoted and correct?

Comment: Yes, you need to put work into your question to get it upvoted. But that doesn't mean you should also be encouraged to accept it over a better answer, just because accepting it would get you another badge. And for all of your comments, you still haven't addressed the point that **it's not an accomplishment to accept your own answer, so it shouldn't be rewarded**.

Comment: @murgatroid99 - it's not an accomplishment to have a highly-upvoted and correct answer - even on your own question?

Comment: I didn't say that. Honestly, I don't even know how you could construe my statements to think that I said that. It is an accomplishment to post a good answer, and that is rewarded with reputation and badges. It is not an accomplishment to ***additionally click a button that looks like a checkmark next to that answer***.

Comment: @murgatroid99 - the *accomplishment* is being the first-and-best answer: ***perhaps*** the "first" part is "too easy" in your mind if you are the asker, but the "best" is certainly not.

Comment: But your proposal isn't about being the best answer. It's not even about writing a good answer, which is already covered by the Good Answer badge. It's about getting an additional award for clicking a button after you've already gotten all of the relevant rewards for writing the good answer. And after this I'm done; you don't seem to understand what I am saying, and I have exhausted every way I can think of saying it.

Comment: @murgatroid99 I do understand what you're saying. But you're not listening to anything I've said - which makes this discussion impossible.

Answer (score 11):

Right now, we have two very closely related badges: Nice Answer (+10 score on an answer) and Enlightened (+10 score and accepted on an answer). You get Nice Answer when 10 people (net) think that your answer is good, and you get Enlightened when 10 people think your answer is good *and* the original asker thinks that your answer helped them the most.

If we allowed self-accepts to grant the Enlightened badge (ignoring the higher score threshold for a moment), then we would have this situation: You get Nice Answer when 10 people think your answer is good, and you would get Enlightened when 10 people think your answer is good *and* you click a button. This would be bad because there would be no additional threshold to get an additional badge.

Replace "Nice Answer" with "Good Answer" in the previous paragraph and you end up with the same problem: you don't have to meet *any* additional standard to get an additional badge; you just have to click a button. **You shouldn't get an extra badge, especially a silver, just for clicking a button.**

Comment: "original asker thinks that your answer helped them the most" - if you accept your answer, *original* poster certainly thinks that your answer helped them the most ;-)

Comment: But there's no boundary to getting it. You don't have to do anything but click a button to get it. I don't know how to word this any differently than **you shouldn't get an extra badge, especially a silver, for clicking a button**.

Comment: @murgatroid99 - then there is no reason to even have the Enlightened badge

Comment: @warren If you didn't ask the question, then *someone else* has to decide to click the button for you to get the badge, and that's a barrier to overcome that should be rewarded. The difference here is between rewarding **clicking a button** and rewarding **getting someone else to decide to click a button**.

Comment: @warren It's the same reason you get reputation for getting an answer accepted, but not if you accept your own answer. Getting an answer accepted means helping someone sufficiently to motivate them to click the check mark; accepting your own answer is **just** clicking a button.

Comment: Yeah, I'm comfortable declining this for this reason alone. Accepting your own answer is fine, but in this case it would pretty much guarantee an extra badge so long as you post a decent answer on a popular enough problem since the other key criterion - being first to post - is fulfilled by definition of "self-answer". Accepting your own answer doesn't award reputation and it shouldn't award badges either.

Comment: @AnnaLear - there still remains the point that `Enlightened` shouldn't exist, based on this answer to the feature-request.

Comment: @warren: come again? Enlightened also requires that you are first to post; if my response to your feature request ever got marked as accepted by you and reached 10 upvotes, I would not get the badge still as murgatroid99 was first to answer.

Comment: @warren: it is *that part of the requirement* that is so easy to game with a self-answer. Just post question and answer together and noone can ever shift you from your first-to-answer position. Plus, the badge is pretty much self-assigned once the vote threshold has been met. So for **self answers** the badge is no better than an extra 'Good Answer' badge.

Comment: @MartijnPieters you're presuming a person will be their own first post (uncommon in gestalt, though it happens) : the vast majority of questions asked are never answered by their asker

Comment: @warren: Yet your feature request is *about self-answers*. I was responding to your assertion that `Enlightened` shouldn't exist at all, which I fail to see supported in this answer.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - yes this request is about self-answers. You're presuming the self-answer will be the first (which is pretty uncommon to start with). And you're presuming it's the best (subjective - maybe it is, maybe it isn't). Fact remains, if you put a higher vote threshold for getting `Enlightened` for self-answered and -accepted questions, you're giving a bonus reason for providing a good answer.

Comment: We don't need "a[nother] bonus reason for providing a good answer". If you post an answer that gets to +25, you are **already** getting 250+ rep, a bronze badge, and a silver badge. We don't need another incentive for people to do all that *and* check the checkbox, whether or not their answer was actually the most helpful.

Answer (score 6):

Take this scenario:

Andy had a problem and solved it, so they posted a self-answer. It was a problem others had too and the answer received upvotes. Betty sees the question but knows of a better way to solve it, so she posts an answer too. Andy agrees Betty's answer is the better solution so he marks her answer as accepted.

Time passes and both answers garner upvotes, Betty's more than Andy's. One day, Andy's answer reaches the threshold for a self-answer Enlightened Badge and Andy thinks to himself: *ooh, shiny badge opportunity*! Andy switches the accepted answer marker to his own answer to gather an easy badge, upsetting Betty who was hoping for a Guru badge and who just lost 15 points.

**This is why we should not have a Enlightened Badge for self accepts**.

Even if Andy changed to accepted answer back to Betty's answer, this was not fair and and too easy. Andy already got a bronze Self-Learner badge for a self-answer, got a Nice Answer badge for ten upvotes (by others) and possibly a Good Answer badge too, plus whatever badges his *question* garnered. Betty's answer can never get the Enlightened badge, because a self-answer can be posted with the question, making it trivial for Andy to be *first to answer*.

Most of all, Enlightened is for those that can answer a question faster and better *when competing with others*; a self-answer is not in that competition.

Comment: this presumes someone would change the accepted answer - ***personally***, I've only done that about once or twice in the history of SO/SE. Do people *really* do it that often?

Comment: @warren: You'd be surprised what people do for badges. They [grind reviews all day](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155561/the-robo-approvers-are-killing-my-will-to-review-edits) if they could, for example.

Comment: @warren: the point of badges is to teach about site features and to encourage desired behaviour. Preferring your own self-answer accept over accepting another post is not something we want to encourage.

Comment: I suppose there are system gamers out there: but they'll exist *whether or not* this exists.